# Como Gerar a Imgem do QRCoder na tela usando C# .NET ASPx com a biblioteca QRCoder

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, qrcode

```
Metodo utilizando a biblioteca QRCoder.
using QRCoder.
    public class GerarQRCoder
    {
        public static void GerarQR(TextBox txtQRCode)
        {

            string Cd = txtQRCode.Text.ToString();
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(Cd, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            Base64QRCode qrCode = new Base64QRCode(qrCodeData);
            // string qrCodeImageAsBase64 = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);

            var imgType = Base64QRCode.ImageType.Jpeg;
            ///Base64QRCode qrCode = new Base64QRCode(qrCodeData);
            string qrCodeImageAsBase64 = qrCode.GetGraphic(20, Color.Black, Color.White, true, imgType);
            var htmlPictureTag = $"<img alt=\"Embedded QR Code\" src=\"data:image/{imgType.ToString().ToLower()};base64,{qrCodeImageAsBase64}\" />";
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho utilizado o ASP. assim porem não consigo passar o src da imagem correto para gerar a imagem na tela, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor.

```
        <asp:Button ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" OnClick="btnGenerate_Click" Text="Gerar QRcode" />
        <asp:Image ID="ImgQRCode" runat="server" src= "src="data:image/{imgType.ToString().ToLower()};base64,{qrCodeImageAsBase64}"
            alt="QR Code" Height="207px" Width="219px"/>
    </p>
```

Comment: não consegui entender a relação entre os dois blocos de código, o método não deveria retornar a string com o conteúdo do QR em base64?

Comment: Olá Leandro desculpe a demora, minha duvida é exatamente essa como retornar esse endereço para o src"" da image na verdade  só esta assim: <asp:Image ID="ImgQRCode" runat="server" src= ""/>, e eu não consigo passar o endereço para gerar a imagem.

Comment: Me parece que você está trabalhando com webforms, você pode atribuir esse source pelo backend no `btnGenerate_Click`ou expor um webmethod para fazer essa requisição via ajax por exemplo